# Outlook 2010 and above

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Same e-mail Id configured on two different PCs in outlook2010. The problem is that if one user on a PC reads e-mail then it automatically Read on another PC. But I would like to make sure the user on 2nd PC should read the e-mail. So how to approach this problem to force 2nd user also should read the e-mail.

Comment: What sort of server are you connected to? IMAP? POP, Exchange?

Answer (score 1):

Generally Outlook will read the status of the message from the server which it is connected to. One thing you can try is to mark the message as unread in Outlook once you are done reading it -- this should mark it as unread in the other client as well.

Edit:

According to the link below you can do the following:

Go to:
View-> Reading Pane-> Options -- then Uncheck the appropriate check boxes.

Here is a link with a solution to your problem (the longer version of what is listed above):
http://www.msoutlook.info/question/250

Comment: This answer is correct. Marking the e-mail as read is a feature of the client, and syncing that change is a feature of IMAP. If you don't want to change the status to "read", make sure the client doesn't change the status, and this answer tells you how.